# how to connect storage account to AAS using powershell script in azure function

Tags: azure, powershell

## ## Get the storage account from which container has to be retrieved

```
$StorageKey = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName
```

getting error:
[Error] Import-AzContext : The term 'Import-AzContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.at run.ps1: line 3+ Import-AzContext+ ________________+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Import-AzContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
2022-02-08T10:26:01.327 [Error] : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.at run.ps1: line 4+++ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand,run.ps1
2022-02-08T10:26:01.468 [Error] param : The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.at run.ps1: line 7+ param+ _____+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (param:String) [], CommandNotFoundException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
2022-02-08T10:26:01.546 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTrigger2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: PowerShell script error. System.Management.Automation: The term 'Import-AzContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2022-02-08T10:26:01.561 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=2339b513-6a62-4687-b418-c31db73fd8c8, Duration=408ms)

Comment: Please [Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this command from my PowerShell `Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -Name MyStorageAccountName` It showed output like this:

[image: Screenshot]

If your desired output is like this then you can update your PowerShell `Az` module once by running this command: `Update-Module Az -Force`.

After successfully updating then try again.

If you didn't install `Az` Module yet then you need to install that module first. You can follow the following steps:

##### Install the Azure Az PowerShell Module

The Azure Az PowerShell module is a rollup module. Installing it downloads the generally available Az PowerShell modules, and makes their cmdlets available for use.
Azure PowerShell has no additional requirements when run on PowerShell 7.0.6 LTS and PowerShell 7.1.3 or higher. To check your PowerShell version, run the following command from within a PowerShell session:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

Install the latest version of PowerShell available for your operating system from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-7.2).

The Azure Az PowerShell module is also supported for use with PowerShell 5.1 on Windows. To use the Azure Az PowerShell module in PowerShell 5.1 on Windows:

- Update to Windows [PowerShell 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2#upgrading-existing-windows-powershell). If you're on Windows 10 version 1607 or higher, you already have PowerShell 5.1 installed.
- Install [.NET Framework 4.7.2 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install).
- Make sure you have the latest version of PowerShellGet. Run this command.

```
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force
```

Now set the execution policy. PowerShell script execution policy must be set to remote signed or less restrictive. Get-ExecutionPolicy -List can be used to determine the current execution policy. Run this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Using the Install-Module cmdlet is the preferred installation method for the Az PowerShell module. Install the Az module for the current user only. This is the recommended installation scope. This method works the same on Windows, macOS, and Linux platforms. Run the following command from a PowerShell session:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

Now Update the Az module by running this command.

```
Update-Module Az -Force
```